How to force new line by textarea in textFit library create by STRML
Since about a week I try to solve that problem. I'm using this library https://github.com/STRML/textFit and I'm try to report this problem but nobody response.
My code: https://codepen.io/Mativve/pen/RwmwRxa
<textarea id="my_field" cols="30" rows="4"></textarea>

<div id="preview"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textfit/2.4.0/textFit.min.js"></script>
<script>
let my_field = $("#my_field");
let preview = $("#preview");

my_field.on("input", () => {
    preview.text( my_field.val().replace(/\n/g, '\n') );
    
    textFit( preview[0], {alignHoriz: false, alignVert: false, minFontSize:10, maxFontSize: 30, reProcess: true, multiLine: true, detectMultiLine: false, widthOnly: false, alignVertWithFlexbox: false} );
});
</script>

I'm tried to replace \n with regex etc. I don't want to using .html to fill the preview because the bad users could use this to XSS (I think).
I don't know what I'm doing wrong :/ Anybody has any idea how to solve this problem?
